# persistence, oracle thin, ORA-12505, TNS listener does not currently know of SID

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, persistence

I'm using 11 g express edition, Eclipse Juno, Java 6

Oracle is up and running even tried shutdown immediate and startup but didn't get SID listener error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.crspdemo.Employee</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:jsfDatabase"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="system"/>
      <!--<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>-->
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**ERROR:**

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
```

Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
**ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor**

**Listner.ora**

[image: listner.ora]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use default SID for XE:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
```